# Slow Delete Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a query:

```
DELETE FROM tableX 
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT TOP(100) id 
    FROM tableX 
    WHERE column1='<some text>' AND column2='<some other text>')
```

This query takes almost 20 seconds to execute.

Looking at the execution plan, it is doing a table scan which is very surprising to me because I have indexes on id (implicitly because this is a PK), column1, and column2.

Is there any way I can rewrite this query to improve its performance?

I am using SQL SERVER CE 4.0.

Comment: You can start by improving your post (indent your code properly) :P

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thanks to Kelix for fixing.

Comment: You're filtering on text too. That is probably causing some slowness as well.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out.  You have to specify an order using ORDER BY in conjunction with TOP. If I specify ORDER BY column2 in the select sub-query, performance went up by more than 100X.  Inspecting the execution plan revealed that doing this caused SQL SERVER CE to use an index seek (instead of a table scan).

Comment: The problem with this fix is that it bloats the size of the database since the query uses the index.  The DB has to rebalance the size of the index table.  So this is not a good solution to my original question.  Aargh.

Comment: "The problem with this fix is that it bloats the size of the database since the query uses the index. "  -- huh?  if the index already exists, as you've indicated, then the database doesn't magically get bigger when you use that index.

Comment: Only sort operations can grow the database file, and it will autoshrink when the file is closed

Comment: Yeah, I took back my comment.  When I deleted the 1500 rows 100 rows at a time using the sql server compact toolbox, it had no effect on the DB size.  However, when I did the same thing in my C++ code using OLE DB, it bloated the DB.  I need to figure out what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a subquery to get the ids from the same table?

Just

```
DELETE TableX
WHERE column1='sometext' AND column2='someothertext'
```

Comment: because I need to use top to get the first 100 rows and top does not work with delete when using sql server ce.